# Data not binding on ButtonClick or SelectionCHange

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, user-controls

I have a page with

```
Page
--UpdatePanel
  -- Buttons
  -- radiobutton

--Uc1
--Uc2
```

On Page load i bind user controls UC1, UC2 with selected value of radiobutton.
But when i select new value in radiobutton it fires selectionchanged event, executes bind method but doesn't update uc1,uc2 values. Similarly I'm trying to get button commandargument when button is clicked and update usercontrols but it doesn't.

What could be causing them not to update even when bind method is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Your Page_Load event fires before the SelectionChanged event. You're performing your binding too early. It would be better to move your binding code into a separate function, and call that code at the times you want to perform binding.

Comment: that is what i'm doing calling bind method (separate function) when page is first loaded or when an event is fired but it doesn't refresh user controls

Answer (score 0):

UC1 and UC2 are not in the UpdatePanel, they will never update unless a full postback is performed. You need to put them inside the UpdatePanel if you want them to update based on partial postbacks initiated inside the UpdatePanel.

It may be counterintuitive when debugging this, because a partial postback still causes the entire page lifecycle to be executed. But nothing outside the UpdatePanel that's being refreshed will be rendered. This is just the way they work.

Comment: If i move them in one updatepanel it doesn't update or work correctly. When i click again it shows old selection data but not current.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code. Is the radio button a trigger for the UpdatePanel? Are you data binding after that event? If your user controls have code in Page_Load that affects their contents, this will already have been run before the event code in the main page.